# How add --pretty option to Jade when i use Codekit?

Tags: html, configuration, pug, codekit

How add `--pretty` option to **Jade** when i use **Codekit**?

Answer (score 0):

I think this usermanual might help you: https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#compass

Matthijs

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Project Settings**, open the **Languages** group, and click **Jade**. Then under the **Jade file settings**, for the **Output Style** option, select **Regular (Indented)**. Hit Apply.

[image: a screenshot of the description above]